# Visual C++ Integer Notation

Tags: c++, integer, declaration

What does `i` in declaration like `10i32` mean in `Visual C++`?
Where can I find documentation on this?
I saw standard declarations in `<limits>` like:

```
#define INT16_MAX        32767i16
#define INT32_MAX        2147483647i32
#define INT64_MAX        9223372036854775807i64
```

Is this notation unsupported in `C`?

Comment: In C, %d is used as integer notation.

Comment: That comment makes no sense in relation to this question.

Comment: Presumably `i32` means that the literal will have type `int32_t`  (this is a MSVC extension)